# encrypt password trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, encryption, triggers, plpgsql

I've tried to encrypt a password in a PostgreSQL database by using a trigger but I can't get it to work, and I don't know where my mistake is.
Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE mms_user ( 
uid serial,
mail text NOT NULL,
passwd text NOT NULL,
usertype integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);

CREATE FUNCTION encrypt_password() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
 NEW.passwd = digest(NEW.passwd, 'sha1');
 RETURN NEW; END; $$LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

 CREATE TRIGGER encrypt_userdata AFTER INSERT ON mms_user EXECUTE PROCEDURE encrypt_password();

 INSERT INTO mms_user values (default, 'who', 'me', 1);
```

It says this when executing:

> ```
> ERROR:  record "new" is not assigned yet
> DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function encrypt_password() line 3 at assignment
> ```

How do I access the record I'm inserting if it's not with `NEW`?

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @RyanVincent Oops, sorry my mistake, I did not mean to address the comment to you, corrected.

Comment: @Roberto Sanchez SHA1 is a cryptographic hash function, not encryption. A hash function is one-way, that is it cannot be reverted to it's input. Encryption os two-way, there is a key and with the key the encrypted data can be reverted to it's original value.

Comment: @zaph I know, I had thought about doing it that way then hashing what the user gives you as a password and compare both to see if it's the same. So you say i should use random uids and concat the uid with the password, am I wrong?

Comment: @RyanVincent the thing is I can't read the NEW values, so I don't see how can I hash the data using a trigger

Comment: @RobertoSanchez See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [Modern, Secure, Salted Password Hashing Made Simple](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#legacy-hashes)

Comment: @zaph I'll have a look at it, thanks!

Comment: @RyanVincent I think i'm gonna do it with the function return approach. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Security and cryptographic considerations aside (see comments), to address your actual PL/pgSQL question:

The trigger function is basically ok. Some cleanup:

```
CREATE FUNCTION encrypt_password()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
 NEW.passwd := digest(NEW.passwd, 'sha1');  -- or some other function?
 RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;  -- don't quote the language name
```

But to make it work, you have to make the trigger **`BEFORE INSERT`**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER encrypt_userdata
BEFORE INSERT ON mms_user
EXECUTE PROCEDURE encrypt_password();
```

I suggest the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-datachanges.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).